# valid fragment of this code in c++

Tags: c++

what is valid form of this code in  visual c++? this does not work i took it from microsoft

```
using namespace System;
int main() {
   Console::WriteLine(__CLR_VER);
}
```

Comment: That's not valid C++, but it's probably valid C++/CLI. Make sure you distinguish between the two languages (and therefore have your project settings match).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good standard C++ approximation:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print text on console you can use:

[cout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzbx67e8%28VS.80%29.aspx) << _("This is my text") << endl;

or

[_tprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx)(_T("This is my text"));